# CV2 Contour from VGG16 model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, opencv

I need to know how to make a cv2 rectangle contour from the model I had?
My project is about Object Detection using Random Forests Algorithm
I Used the VGG16 model to extract features and put extract the result by Random forests

```
feature_extractor=VGG16()
feature_extractor.layers.pop()
feature_extractor=Model(inputs=feature_extractor.inputs,outputs=feature_extractor.layers[-1].output)
X_for_RF = feature_extractor.predict(x_train,verbose=1)
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 42) 
model.fit(X_for_RF,y_train)
```

Example: if i have apple images and i made training model about it .
now i need when i enter image it make rectangle on the apple
**i need to make detection contour not classfication**

[image: Like this]

Comment: explain, do you want to do classification (identify/classify), or detection (determine where something is)?

Comment: Make contour detection by cv2

Comment: You mean to say, you just need to put a bounding box ( rectangles) around your objects ?

Comment: yes, that's what I need